# Logic symbols $\forall$ and $\exists$

Tags: logic, quantifiers

What is the difference between the statements

$$\exists K> 0\, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\, : |f(x)|< K   $$
and 
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\, \exists K> 0\, : |f(x)|< K   $$
I know what $\forall$ and $\exists$ mean but I just can't see a difference between the two statements? I know that say $f(x)=x^4$ has the first property I just don't really understand why. Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: In the first, $K$ works for all $x$; in the second, $K$ can change depending on the particular $x$ you're considering.

Comment: The same difference between "Every 90 seconds, an american die from cancer" and "An american die from cancer every 90 seconds".

Comment: Confer to the musketeers: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unus_pro_omnibus,_omnes_pro_uno

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's write the two statements with some paratheses: 
$$\tag 1 \exists K > 0 \, \bigl(\forall x \in \mathbf R: |f(x)| < K\bigr) $$
and 
$$ \tag 2 \forall x \in \mathbf R \, \bigl(\exists K > 0 : |f(x)| < K \bigr) $$
Let's start with (2). So forall $x \in \mathbf R$, it has to be true that 
$$ \tag{$2_x$} \exists K > 0 : |f(x)| < K $$
with is (obviously) true: $|f(x)|$ is a real number, there are larger ones, say $K = |f(x)| + 1$. So for each $x$ we can give a $K$.

Now, let's look at (1). Here we have to give **one** $K$, such that 
$$ \tag{$1_K$} \forall x \in \mathbf R : |f(x)| < K $$
Note that $K$ must not depend on $x$, it may depend on $f$, of course, but depending on $f$, (1) may be false. $(1_K)$ says that $f$ is bounded by $K$, if $f$ is unbounded, as $f(x) = x^4$ is (1) is false.

Answer (score 1):

"There is a human $A$ such that for every other human $B$, $A$ is a parent of $B$."

"For every human $B$, there is a human $A$ such that $A$ is a parent of $B$."

I think you'll agree that the first is false and the second (in the absence of the Axiom of Death) is true.

Answer (score 0):

With the first, you get a bounded function. The second is a null property, since you can take $K=2|f(x)|$ for every $x\in\Bbb R$.

---

And $f(x)=x^4$ is not a bounded function.